# Yarn install fails after previously working

Tags: google-app-engine, yarnpkg, google-appengine-node

Just yesterday I started getting this error when trying to deploy my app to App Engine. Anyone else experiencing this? This was working as of yesterday. Might be related to this https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3277

```
Step 1 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
latest: Pulling from google_appengine/nodejs
Digest: sha256:94812e54a19537ae637ab6fc11d7c66a55c41857b3b37e90385b563a2393edc0
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs:latest
 ---> 459db92cf06b
Step 2 : RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=6.10'
 ---> Running in 552f7df961d6
 ---> 5799b1e5164c
Removing intermediate container 552f7df961d6
Step 3 : RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --global yarn
 ---> Running in 1cc4eef305f4
/nodejs/bin/yarn -> /nodejs/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/nodejs/bin/yarnpkg -> /nodejs/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/nodejs/lib
`-- yarn@0.23.4 

 ---> 772d02a8d2aa
Removing intermediate container 1cc4eef305f4
Step 4 : COPY . /app/
 ---> c8b99c95b77b
Removing intermediate container d58b61b73100
Step 5 : RUN yarn install --production ||   ((if [ -f yarn-error.log ]; then       cat yarn-error.log;     fi) && false)
 ---> Running in 24cec67fbf5b
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'v8-compile-cache'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/nodejs/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:25:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --production ||   ((if [ -f yarn-error.log ]; then       cat yarn-error.log;     fi) && false)' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:926dc1a14e6f7eb5b3462b5c1d491aa6c73090291167ac2bf181c026b05f19da" failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the recently updated base Nodejs image used by the App Engine Flexible environment.  [A public issue has been filed to track this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37978206).  I recommend starring this issue to receive updates.

Comment: great, thanks for the link!